# How to set up a shared folder in QEMU KVM?

Tags: linux, kvm

I tried to create a folder using this guide: https://cialu.net/qemu-kvm-on-ubuntu-and-sharing-files-between-host-and-guests/.

But after entering this command in the Kali guest OS:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L /vmshare /home/guest-username/vmshare
```

I get this error:

```
mount: /home/ivan/Desktop/vmshare: special device /vmshare does not exist.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after a failed mount system call.
```